# Custom Callout Bubble iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am developing app with mapview functionality. I want to show custom pin image on mapview, click on that open custom callout bubble with image and title. With click on that callout bubble view I would like to do some functionality. How to achieve this? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=callout+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Head over to **[CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/)** for custom controls. I bet you'll find something useful for your requirement.

Here are some search results from CocoaControls:

- **[Callout](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=callout+)**
- **[Bubble](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bubble)**
- **[Popup](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popup)**

---

#### Custom Pin Image

There are already questions on SO which answer this **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699171/how-do-i-add-custom-pins-to-the-iphone-mapkit)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950698/custom-pin-on-mkmapview-in-ios)** and many more. I daresay you'll find your answer among them. Basically, the code is

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

    NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"CustomViewAnnotation";
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    if(!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                  reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier]];
    }
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_location_pin.png"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout= YES;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: I have set custom image as annotation, now i want to open custom callout bubble on click of that image. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can use the `MKMapViewDelegate`'s method `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:` to handle the click and present a popup from that method.

Comment: Oh and yes, I suppose if you are showing your own custom callout, you will need to turn off the default callout by setting `canShowCallout` to `NO`. Play around with the code and see if you get what you want.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create custom Annotations.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check out it: https://github.com/grgcombs/MultiRowCalloutAnnotationView

Hope, It will may help you,

:)